# Database instance/catalog/schema management with JUnit

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a large number of tests that run against a relational database via JDBC.  At the moment many of those test classes create their own schemas and schema objects (tables, etc).  We have also seen that for in-memory databases, each test is recreating the actual database instance.  All told the tests take way longer to run than they should.

So I want to move (as much as possible) the tests to use a number of predefined schemas and have some way to hook creating and dropping of these schemas to JUnit lifecycle.  I am initially thinking a Rule that tells which catalogs/schemas are in use by that test.  The Rule would then coordinate with some central registry to create the catalogs/schemas on first use and drop them after all tests are done.

Would that be a good way to go about this?  Would that be the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I know of DbUnit, although I do not know it well.  However, I do not *think* DbUnit fits the requirements.  DbUnit, as I understand it, is more meant to work with database data (aka, insert data into tables).  I am looking for something else; I need to be able to execute the CREATE CATALOG, CREATE SCHEMA, etc command and drop after.  Also, iiuc, DbUnit does its work for each test; again, I am trying to get away from that - I want to do these steps for a number of test classes together.